# Distributed data storage for a large sensor network

Tags: hashtable, distributed, p2p, bittorrent

Recently, I've been working on a problem involving sensor network data collection and dissemination, and I've hit a wall. I read through [this](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sylvia/papers/p53-ratnasamy.pdf) paper on geographic hash tables and I think it's brilliant, but I can't find any reference implementations of systems that implement this as a distributed hash table (or implement it at all, actually).

I was hoping someone could provide some input on what the best way forward would be. Basically I'm looking for a data store that can be adapted to operate in (more or less) the same way that a distributed hash table would (the bittorrent protocol uses one). The catch is that instead of linking just one object to its data (as is the case with a strictly torrent file -> torrent contents scheme) I need to be able to relate the data to data with a similar collection parameter. In the GHT example (linked above), this is done by using the geographic coordinates of the sensors. This would work for me, but I'm finding little to no information on how to effectively distribute this. Ideally I would like to be able to just use the same P2P protocol scheme that a DHT uses.

Comment: *"The catch is that instead of linking just one object to its data (as is the case with a strictly torrent file -> torrent contents scheme) I need to be able to relate the data to data with a similar collection parameter."*  can you elaborate further on that? since it seems to be the core of your problem.

Comment: @the8472 Certainly. Let's say that all of our sensors are located in a 10x10 grid, with a location being described by its coordinated (x,y). I would, ideally, like to be able to have some type of lookup scheme where someone could just do lookup((2,10),(5,10)). That would be the equivalent of taking everything from [2,10] in the x plane and [5,10] in the y plane. This is not the exact case, but for continuous parameters (i.e. there's no simple integer lookups, which we could do really simply if we just need to lookup 2,3,...,10 sequentially) I can't find any way of distributing that data.

Answer (score 1):

A DHT itself is fairly hostile to any kind of distributed window query because the hashing erases all information of the data to achieve random key distribution.

I can see several solutions to that, but none of them will just work out of the box, they either require significant modifications to a DHT or implementing a new p2p protocol from scratch.

- use the DHT as storage for an overlay data structure which supports range queries. paper: [distributed segment tree over DHT](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/conferences/iptps06/papers/Zheng-DST06.pdf)
- if the data can somehow be massaged to be essentially uniformly distributed over the keyspace one could forego the hashing and just map it directly to keyspace coordinates
- conversely, if you can find a scheme in which nodes adjust their position to cover hotspots more than underutilized regions you can forgo the hashing because non-uniformity in the dataset is compensated by non-uniformity of the node distribution
- you can forego the DHT layout completely and just organize nodes themselves according to a spatial data structure, e.g. as a [distributed R-tree](http://cedric.cnam.fr/fichiers/RC1110.pdf)

Additional piece of information: Any higher-dimensional order can be packed into a 1-dimensional one while preserving locality by using a [z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve)

useful keywords when searching for papers: "distributed [spatial index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index)", "distributed window query", "distributed range query"

Comment: Thanks for the response! After doing some more research (those search terms being exactly what I was missing) I think that I now know what I'm going to do. To prevent sybil attacks, I'm using a hashcat-like proof of work system. I think that I can utilize that proof of work mechanism to determine the keyspace 'hotspots;' the most hashed-on portions of the space are the most active. All that I was missing was a way to, as you said, pack the data while preserving locality.